# jQuery-UI tabs - load just once

Tags: jquery-ui

I'd like the load content of my tabs thru AJAX, but only on the first tab click. Now the tabs gets loaded every time I click on any tab. Is this possible ?

My html

```
<div id="tabContainer">
<ul>
<li><a href="/Home/Tab1">Tab1</a></li>
<li><a href="/Home/Tab2">Tab2</a></li>
<li><a href="/Home/Tab3">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

EDIT

I cannot use the Cache option,because the content in the tabs may change..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) or [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) the link after performing the load().  Or if you want to allow multiple refreshes of the tab contents you could remove whatever was loaded the first time and re- load().

You could also change the id of the link tag and add a secondary behavior to fall back on.

Answer (score 11):

```
$(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.tab.data("loaded")) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
                ui.ajaxSettings.cache = false;
                ui.panel.html('<img src="images/prettyPhoto/dark_square/loader.gif" width="24" height="24" style="vertical-align:middle;"> Loading...');
                ui.jqXHR.done(function() {
                    ui.tab.data( "loaded", true );
                });
                ui.jqXHR.fail(function () {
                    ui.panel.html(
                    "Couldn't load Data. Plz Reload Page or Try Again Later.");
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: This solution works right away with current version of jquery-ui (1.10), which lacks the cache option.

Answer (score 3):

The option "cache" may resolve the problem .

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  cache: true 
  //some other options 
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#option-cache

Comment: **Using {cache:true} results in bad behaviour**: on one tab there is an ajax form, that refreshes its content after ajax success using jquery; so after changing data on that form and refreshing page by clicking refresh button in browser I get old html of that form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can catch the event, check if the tab already has content and stop the ajax if it does .

e.g.

```
$('#example').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
         if($('#' + ui.panel.id).html() != ''){
            return;
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: I like your idea,but somehow it does not work. If I click second time on the tab,the If statement is true but the tabs gets loaded again anyway.